# Print values of columns in a range in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

In an excel spreadsheet, I want to print the values of a column in a range. In the attached image 0.16146 to 0.01147.
So far I can do this for one value ="My values:"&TEXT(F8,"#,##0.0000")

How can I do this for a range of values ($F8:$F19) without explicitly writing this out?

[Column of calculated value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOBmN.png)

Comment: Are you willing to put your data in an access DB?  If so   **select * from table where column between 0.01147 and 0.16146;**

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean, but do you want the 'My values ...' text to go under the current example? If so why don't you just autofill the existing formula down the required number of rows?

Comment: I should have more clear.. I want to generate an explicit representation of a sum of the cells in a column, without actually summing it.